# Trying to filter an array and return a new array with the met criteria

Tags: arrays, object, push

Im trying to make a function that returns an Array (javascript). The original array contains objects (pizzas) and I have to return a **new array** WITHOUT the pizzas that contain pineapple on it. I dont seem to understand why it doesnt work.

I have tried to declare a new array and push() the [i] values that meet the criteria (!== 'pineapple'). But im clearly missing something.

I just started learning JS this week so tools like filter and map aren't possible for me yet.

thanks in advance!

```js
    const pizzas = [
    { type: 'margherita', size: '5' },
    { type: 'funghi', size: '6' },
    { type: 'hawaii', size: '7' },
    { type: 'vegetarian', size: '8' },
    { type: 'pineapple', size: '9' },
  ];

function filterPizzas(pizzas) {
    const noPineapple = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < pizzas.length; i++) {
      if (pizzas[i].type !== 'pineapple') {
        noPineapple.push(pizzas[i]);
      }
    }
  return noPineapple;
  }
```

Comment: What programming language is?

Comment: Why do you have a `catalogue` AND a `pizzas` array? What is the purpose of each? Because in your `for` loop you use `catalogue`'s index... but use it to check `pizzas[i]`...but then you push `catalogue[i]`? Maybe updating the question with some sample content  for `pizzas` might help

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it was Javascript.  I guess you are right. I moved the array out of the function and named it pizzas. I chose a different name because I dont know if would create a conflict. Also I didnt reference the right thing, should have looked for catalogue[i] rather than pizza[i]. I have updated the code, but still doesnt pass as valid.

Comment: @JorgeMendez your code works fine. The only thing I'd say is missing is the function call at this point. You are *declaring* your `filterPizzas` function, but you never actually execute it

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost correct, although there is no use for storing the catalogue inside your FilterPizzas function and then also take in pizzas as a function argument. I assume you want to pass this list of pizzas (your catalogue) to your function and then return the filtered result.

```
const pizzas = [
  { type: 'margherita', price: '5' },
  { type: 'funghi', price: '6' },
  { type: 'hawaii', price: '7' },
  { type: 'vegetarian', price: '8' },
  { type: 'pineapple', price: '9' },
]

function filterPizzas(pizzas) {
  const filteredPizzas = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < pizzas.length; i++) {
    if (pizzas[i].type !== 'pineapple') {
      filteredPizzas.push(pizzas[i]);
    }
  }
return filteredPizzas
}
```

Have a look in the console of this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-js-filter-function-zxvyn4?file=/src/index.js) example.

Comment: I was going insane, the learning platform returns an error when the code works fine in VScode. As you have it written (which i tried before) works fine but the platform wont accept it. I was going insane, I will contact them. Thanks very much for the input!.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
 function filterPizzas(pizzas) {
              const filteredPizzas = [];
              for (let i = 0; i < pizzas.length; i++) {
                const pizza = pizzas[i];
                const pizzaType = pizza.type;
                const isNotPineapple = pizzaType !== "pineapple";
                
                if (isNotPineapple) {
                  filteredPizzas.push(pizza);
                }
              }
              return filteredPizzas;
            }
```

Option 2:

```
function filterPizzas(pizzas) {
  
  let array = pizzas.filter(pizza => {
   return pizza.type != 'pineapple';
 });
 return array;
}
```